# Guardar diferente valor del que tiene un select en value

Tags: php, html5, mysqli

```html
<div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="inputBox">
                  <div class="inputText">*Puesto</div>
                     <select class="input"  name="puesto" required>
                      <option value="" disabled selected></option>
                      <option value="Vendedor">Vendedor</option>
                      <option value="Vendedor Comisionista">Vendedor Comisionista</option>
                      <option value="Gerente">Gerente</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
```

Mi duda es saber como hacer para que se guarde ese value y a la vez otro value como 1, 2 y 3 dependiendo el valor seleccionado en un campo de mi tabla llamado tipo (los valores de vendedor..se guardan en una tabla llamada area, todo bien hasta ahí).

Espero me puedan ayudar.

```
require("conexion.php");

$nom = $_POST['nombrev'];
$ape = $_POST['apev'];
$correo = $_POST['email'];
$clave = $_POST['clave'];
$area = $_POST['puesto'];
$fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
$gen = $_POST['genero'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];



//echo "<script> alert('".$nom."'); </script>";
//echo "<script> alert('".$ape."'); </script>";
//echo "<script> alert('".$correo."'); </script>";

mysqli_query($conexion,"INSERT INTO usuarioss (nombre, apellido, correo, telefono, clave, sexo, area, fecha) VALUES ('$nom', '$ape', '$correo', '$tel', '$clave', '$gen', '$area', '$fecha')");
```

Comment: ¿Podrías aclarar la pregunta e indicar el código PHP que estás usando y el problema o error que tienes en él? Debes recuperar `$_POST["puesto"]` en PHP y trabajar con él. ¿Lo estás haciendo? ¿Qué dificultad tienes? ¿Hay un error? ¿Qué error?

Comment: Pero qué es lo que quieres guardar en sí, no se entiende... Por favor, explica ¿?

Comment: Que tal, ya agregue el codigo php que utiliz para insertar los datos a la base de datos, mi unico problema es que aparte de guardar el valor del select que viene ahi, quiero que se guarde si selecciono gerente se guarde en el campo 'tipo' con un 3, si es vendedor con un dos y así.

Comment: Todo funciona bien solo esa es mi duda.

Comment: Ok, Ahora entiendo. Puedes tener un array asociativo para buscar ahí el dato numérico (esto sólo conviene si son pocos valores). O bien pasar dos datos en el `value` y hacer `explode` en PHP. Ahora te muestro dos ejemplos en una respuesta. Sin embargo, me pregunto por qué guardas el dato alfanumérico y el numérico al mismo tiempo. Intuyo que no estás implementando un modelo relacional, pues de ser así poniendo el valor numérico en cada `value` de los `option` bastaría, pero esa es otra historia...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto de puede solucionar de varias formas.

### 1. Si son pocos datos

Puedes tener un array asociativo en PHP y obtener el valor de ese array:

```
$arrPuestos=array (1=>'Vendedor', 2=>'Vendedor Comisionista', 3=>'Gerente');
$area = $_POST['puesto'];
$id_area= array_search($area,$arrPuestos);
```

Ahí obtendrás en `$id_area` el valor `1,2,3` según el caso... Nótese que puse a propósito los valores numéricos a la izquierda, como índices del array, porque es la práctica común, y por eso nos vemos obligados a recurrir a `array_search` para buscar los `ids`. Lo lógico sería tener una tabla relacional con los ids y listo.

---

### 2. Si son muchos datos

Puedes poner en los `value` ambos datos con un separador y luego hacer `explode` en PHP para obtenerlos por separado.

**HTML:**

Usaremos una estrategia que consiste en poner los valores separados por `|`. Es una forma simple de enviar varios datos desde la etiqueta `value`.

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="inputBox">
                  <div class="inputText">*Puesto</div>
                     <select class="input"  name="puesto" required>
                      <option value="" disabled selected></option>
                      <option value="1|Vendedor">Vendedor</option>
                      <option value="2|Vendedor Comisionista">Vendedor Comisionista</option>
                      <option value="3|Gerente">Gerente</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
```

**PHP:**

Obtendremos los valores por separado con la ayuda de `explode`.

```
$area = explode('|',$_POST['puesto']);
$id_area=$area[0];
$str_area=$area[1];
```

---

### 3. En HTML5

En vez de la opción 2, podrías recurrir a atributos `data-*`, pero en ese caso deberías usar Ajax para postear los datos al servidor.

Comment: Pero como guardo el numero en el la tabla tipo? porque las palabras las guardo en la tabla 'área' y los números quiero que se guarden en la tabla 'tipo'.